# Read MP4 video metadata without playing it

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I am loading a MP4 file in flash using flie reference to server, Now I want to check the size and codec of the video, if the size is less than 640X360, then I don't want to allow it for upload.

I have made filter to choose only MP4 files.

```
var aryFileFilters:Array = new Array(); 
aryFileFilters.push(new FileFilter("Video Files", "*.mp4;*.avi;*.mov;*.flv"));  
aryFileFilters.push(new FileFilter("Audio Files", "*.mp3;*.wav"));  
objFileRef.browse(aryFileFilters);
objFileRef.addEventListener("select", onUploadFile);
```

I have check over internet and found no way to do it, If you have something  please share.

Thanks in advance.